# Process builder not working on update records

Tags: process-builder, approval-process, automation

I am working on a process builder, which is triggered whenever a grant contract object is created/edited. Here two objects are used: grant contract the child and grant the parent object.
These are the conditions used:

[image]
[image]

Here the grant contract stage should be updated with the stage contract received according to my requirement; and this should happen, if the parent object grant's stage is post award and substage is training in progress.

The flow is working, when I create a grant contract; but it isn't working, when I update the grant record to meet the requirement and then update the grant contract. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

While selecting the object, also check the option"When the record is created or Edited" as shown in below image

[image]

Comment: I have already set it as "the record is being created or edited".